# WebSocket server health check with curl

Tags: curl, websocket

I am trying to implement a healthcheck for WebSocket server with `curl`.

```
curl --include --no-buffer \
    --header "Connection: Upgrade" \
    --header "Upgrade: websocket" \
    --header "Sec-WebSocket-Key: SGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ==" \
    --header "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13" \
    http://localhost:3000
```

I send an HTTP request to do the handcheck, and receive an `HTTP 101` as expected :

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: qGEgH3En71di5rrssAZTmtRTyFk=
```

My issue is that after receiving that response, curl will just hang.

Is there any way to tell curl to exit after that successful handshake?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Connection: close` instead of `Connection: Upgrade` in order to specify that the connection should be closed after the completion of the response :

```bash
curl --include --no-buffer \
    --header "Connection: close" \
    --header "Upgrade: websocket" \
    --header "Sec-WebSocket-Key: SGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ==" \
    --header "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13" \
    http://localhost:3000
```

Comment: can I translate this to be programmatically done by node http module? https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

Comment: would this be considered a valid way to do the same request https://pastebin.com/xhAqpHkH